# Create new tool for Gedit LaTeX plugin

Tags: plugins, latex, gedit

I would like to create a new tool for the [Gedit LaTeX Plugin](http://www.michaels-website.de/gedit-latex-plugin/), but I run into two problems.

First, I cannot select "New" from Edit / Preferences / Plugins / LaTeX Plugin 0.2 / Configure Plugin / Tools. I tried first the version in the Ubuntu repositories and then the version on Sourceforge, but both don't allow to create a new tool: the button is there, but if I click on it, nothing happens.

Second, if I edit one of the existing tools, I really don't have an idea on how to change the relevant commands. I tried with:
Code:

```
latex
bibtex
latex
pdflatex
evince
```

but it obviously doesn't work.
Can you advise me on that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What type of plugin do you want to create? In much cases Kile is already a good Integrated LaTeX Environment on Linux/Ubuntu (I guess you use gedit on Linux). I never had problems I couldn't solve with Kile.

Comment: Basically I need a one-click button to execute the following sequence: latex bibtex latex pdflatex evince. Kile is good, but I would prefer to use Gedit because of its cleaner interface, better spelling check utility, and Gnome compatibility.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for SO since it's about Gedit plugins, not LaTeX.